# How to fix child in views

Tags: android, layout

I  am  facing   problem     in    fixing the    child  in  particular     place
in  views   or   layout.

1. Can  I  fix   the     child   at      the  starting   and   ending  of  Layout  directly ?
2. Can I   fix  the    child  at  the   starting  or  ending  of the   view  directly ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you understand the different types of layouts and what is their intended purpose?

About the layouts, please look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html
About placing child views in another view, look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html

P.S. You seem to ask lots of questions, without having a good perspective for Android. Maybe reading a book or two about the platform will be better than trying to have every little problem in your project solved here.

Comment: See  I  have    very    good   experience   in java   domain 
But I am   new   in   Android.Although I   am       working    on a  challenging   project ,I may    need   some  help.You     may  see     I asked   the  saME  QUESTION  AGAIN AND AGAIN  for  attracting    the  notice .